# Error while installing Net::SSLEAY on Rasbian

Tags: perl, ssl, openssl, debian, raspbian

Im trying to get Openssl & Net:SSLeay to work on my Raspberry PI. I was following [this documentary](http://www.webmin.com/ssl.html) to install the stuff, but i ran into some error.

When im Running

> perl Meakefile.PL

it returns this

```
Checking for OpenSSL-0.9.6j or 0.9.7b or newer...
You have OpenSSL-1.1.1d installed in /usr
That's is newer than what this module was tested with (0.9.6j
or 0.9.7b). You should
consider checking if there is a newer release of this module
available. Everything will probably work OK, though.
*** Could not figure out which C compiler was used to compile /usr/bin/openssl. It is essentiall that OpenSSL, perl, and Net::SSLeay are compiled with the same compiler and flags. Mixing and matching compilers is not supported. at Makefile.PL line 140.
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Net::SSLeay
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
```

After the command im supposed to

> make install

but this just outputs this:

uploaded it to [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/ScarVite/e59e3f88ceadbcff9515cad07056260e), since I couldn't paste it all here.

and yes, before you ask, i already installed libssl-dev.

I've tried installing & fixing this for several hours now, i hope you can help me

Comment: Which version of `Net::SSLeay` are you trying to install? (Run: `grep '$VERSION =' lib/Net/SSLeay.pm`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP did not provide information about working environment. What Linux distribution is installed in Raspberry? What version of perl is installed into the environment?

As the question mentioned **Raspbian** I assume that some form of Debian Linux distribution is pre-installed into *Raspberry* board

If Raspberry pre-installed with some *Debian* distribution then see if **Net::SSLEay** available as package

`apt-cache search -n ssleay`

if the package is available then install it with following command

`apt-get install [package_name]`

If Raspberry pre-installed with something else then try following

`cpan install Net::SSLeay`

or

`cpanm install Net::SSLeay`

If the above does not work then try to use

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install Net::SSLeay
```

Note: the installation of some perl modules require *C compiler* be available to compile binaries

Please see following [webpage](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=49735) for possible answer to your question.

Comment: I have Raspian GNU/Linux 10 installed.
I installed it using apt-get install ```libnet-ssleay-perl``` and it worked.
Thanks